# Responsive menu in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have an issue with js. I want to make an responsive menu. I mean when I am on start page the start page is on first place on the list. If I am on contact page the contact is first in the list. `var planet = ["Start","Contact", "First","Second", "Third", "Fourth", "Fifth", "Sixth"];` `<div class="name_container"><p class="pn">Start</p><p class="more">READ MORE</p></div>` The menu is a circle with icons that are moving on it. First element in list is on bottom of the  circle. On conclusion I need change the list dinamicly in js script depends on subpage i am on. I know i can create several js files and it will work, but i wonna try it by js or HTML or u have some ideas.
Thanks from any help

```js
var element = document.getElementById('mobile_control');
var hammertime = new Hammer(element);


hammertime.get('swipe').set({ direction: Hammer.DIRECTION_ALL });
hammertime.on('swipeleft', function(ev) {
  cmove("prev");
});
hammertime.on('swiperight', function(ev) {
  cmove("next");
});

$(".action").on("click", function(){
  cmove($(this).attr('id'));
});

$('.title').each(function(){
  $(this).html("Earth".replace("<span class='letter'>$&</span>"));
});


var angle = 0;
var planet_id = 0;

function cmove(dir){
  var n_planet = 8, next_id;
  var prev, next;
  var top = $("#pl"+ planet_id);
  var orbit = $(".planet_container");
  
  top.removeClass("pt");
  
  if(planet_id == 0){
    prev = $("#pl"+ (n_planet-1));
    next = $("#pl"+ (planet_id+1)%n_planet);
  }else{
    prev = $("#pl"+ (planet_id-1));
    next = $("#pl"+ (planet_id+1)%n_planet);
  }
  
  if(dir == "prev"){
    next_id = (planet_id + 1) % n_planet;
    angle -= 45;
    next.addClass("pt");
    planet_id++;
  }else{
    if(planet_id == 0){
      next_id = 7;
      planet_id = 7;
    }else{
      next_id = planet_id-1;
      --planet_id;
    }
    angle += 45;
    prev.addClass("pt");
  }
  
  $('.pn').each(function(){
    $(this).html(planet[next_id].replace( "<span class='letter'>$&</span>"));
  });
  
  anime.timeline({})
  .add({
    targets: '.pn .letter',
    translateX: [40,0],
    translateZ: 0,
    opacity: [0,1],
    easing: "easeOutExpo",
    duration: 1200,
    delay: function(el, i) {
      return 500 + 30 * i;
    }
  });
  
  orbit.css("transform", "rotateZ(" + angle + "deg)");
  

}
var planet = ["Start","Contact", "First","Second", "Third", "Fourth", "Fifth", "Sixth"];

let loocation_path = location.pathname.split('/');

var path = loocation_path[loocation_path.length - 1];

switch(path){
      case 'index.html':
        while(planet[0] != 'Start'){
          let head = planet.shift();
          planet.push(head);
        };
        var nazwa = document.getElementById('show_pathname');
        nazwa.innerHTML = "Start";
        break;
      case 'contact.html':
        while(planet[0] != 'Contact'){
          let head = planet.shift();
          planet.push(head);
        };
        var nazwa = document.getElementById('show_pathname');
        nazwa.innerHTML = "Contact";     
        break;   
}

const planets = document.querySelectorAll('.moon');

var moon_id = 0;

function moon(direction){

  var n_planet = 8, moon_next;

  if(direction == "prev"){
    moon_next = (moon_id + 1) % n_planet;
    moon_id++;
  } else {
    if(moon_id == 0){
      moon_next = 7;
      moon_id = 7;
    } else {
      moon_next = moon_id - 1;
      --moon_id;
    }
  };

  planets.forEach( ( planet, i ) => {
    if ( i === moon_next ) {
        planet.style.visibility = 'visible';
    } else {
        planet.style.visibility = 'hidden';
    }
  } );
};
```

```css
body {
    color: #444444;
    font-size: 1rem;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0; 
}
.t-site-header {
    padding-top: 20px;
    height: 30vh;
}
.full_container {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    width: 100vmin;
    height: 100%;
    margin: auto;
    z-index: 100;
  }
  .full_container .bottom {
    position: absolute;
    transform: rotate(180deg);
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 28vh;
  }
  .full_container .bottom .nav {
    width: 100%;
    height: 40px;
    padding-top: 15px;
    display: block !important;
  }
  .full_container .bottom .nav span {
    color: #999;
    cursor: pointer;
  }
  .full_container .bottom .nav span i {
    font-size: 40px;
    font-weight: 200;
  }
  .full_container .bottom .nav span:nth-child(1) {
    padding-left: 10vmin;
  }
  .full_container .bottom .nav span:nth-child(2) {
    padding-right: 10vmin;
    float: right;
  }
  .full_container .bottom .orbit {
    position: absolute;
    top: 5vh;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vmin;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border: 3px solid #eee;
    margin: auto;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
  }
  .full_container .bottom .orbit .planet_container {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    border-radius: 50%;
    transition: transform 0.7s ease-in;
  }
  .full_container .bottom .orbit .planet_container .planet {
    position: absolute;
    border-radius: 50%;
    width: 5vmin;
    height: 5vmin;
    transition: transform 0.4s linear;
    will-change: transform;

  }
  .full_container .bottom .orbit .planet_container .pt {
    transition: transform 0.4s ease-in;
    transform: scale(1.7);
    will-change: transform;
    -webkit-animation: spin 0.4s;
            animation: spin 0.4s;
   
  }
  /* */
  .full_container .bottom .orbit .planet_container .earth {
    background: url(https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/other-icons/48/app_window-512.png) no-repeat center center / contain;
    top: -2.5vmin;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin: auto;
   /*  transform: rotate(180deg)*/
  }
  .full_container .bottom .orbit .planet_container .earth .mars .jupiter .saturn .uranus .neptune .mercury .venus .moon span {
    top: -1vmin;
    left: -1vmin;
  }
  .full_container .bottom .orbit .planet_container .mars {
    background: url(https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/other-icons/48/app_window-512.png) no-repeat center center / contain;
    right: 12vmin;
    top: 12vmin;
   /*  transform: rotate(-135deg)*/
  }
  .full_container .bottom .orbit .planet_container .jupiter {
    background: url(https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/other-icons/48/app_window-512.png) no-repeat center center / contain;
    right: -2.5vmin;
    bottom: 46.5vmin;
   /*  transform: rotate(-90deg) scale(1.7);*/
  }
  .full_container .bottom .orbit .planet_container .saturn {
    background: url(https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/other-icons/48/app_window-512.png) no-repeat center center / contain;
    right: 12vmin;
    bottom: 12vmin;
   /*  transform: rotate(-45deg) scale(1.7);*/
  
  }
  .full_container .bottom .orbit .planet_container .uranus {
    background: url(https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/other-icons/48/app_window-512.png) no-repeat center center / contain;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
    margin: auto;
    bottom: -2.5vmin;
   /*  transform: rotate(0deg) scale(1.7);*/
  }
  .full_container .bottom .orbit .planet_container .neptune {
    background: url(https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/other-icons/48/app_window-512.png) no-repeat center center / contain;
    left: 12vmin;
    bottom: 12vmin;
   /*  transform: rotate(45deg) scale(1.7);*/
  }
  .full_container .bottom .orbit .planet_container .mercury {
    background: url(https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/other-icons/48/app_window-512.png) no-repeat center center / contain;
    left: -2.5vmin;
    bottom: 46.5vmin;
   /*  transform: rotate(90deg) scale(1.7);*/
  }
  .full_container .bottom .orbit .planet_container .venus {
    background: url(https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/other-icons/48/app_window-512.png) no-repeat center center / contain;
    left: 12vmin;
    top: 12vmin;
   /*  transform: rotate(135deg) scale(1.7);*/
  
  }
  .full_container .bottom .orbit .name_container {
    position: absolute;
    display: flex;
    width: auto;
    margin: auto;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    top: 8vh;
    text-align: center;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    transform: rotate(180deg);
  }
  .full_container .bottom .orbit .name_container .more {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 8px 0;
    color: #bbb;
    font-weight: 500;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: color 0.2s;
  }
  .full_container .bottom .orbit .name_container .more:hover {
    color: #888;
    transition: color 0.3s;
  }
  .full_container .bottom .orbit .name_container .pn {
    font-size: 25px;
    color: #666;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    padding-bottom: 4px;
    letter-spacing: 4px;
    padding-left: 8px;
    border-bottom: 3px solid #bbb;
  }
  .full_container .bottom .orbit .name_container .pn .letter {
    display: inline-block;
    line-height: 1em;
    opacity: 0;
  }
  
  .moon {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    -webkit-animation: planet_rotation 2s infinite linear;
            animation: planet_rotation 2s infinite linear;
    visibility: hidden;
  }
  .moon span {
    width: 0.8vmin;
    height: 0.8vmin;
    background: black;
    border-radius: 50%;
    position: absolute;
  }
  
  @-webkit-keyframes planet_rotation {
    from {
      transform: rotate(0deg);
    }
    to {
      transform: rotate(360deg);
    }
  }
  
  @keyframes planet_rotation {
    from {
      transform: rotate(0deg);
    }
    to {
      transform: rotate(360deg);
    }
  }

  @-webkit-keyframes spin {
    from {
      transform: rotate(0deg);
    }
    to {
      transform: rotate(360deg);
    }
  }
  
  @keyframes spin {
    from {
      transform: rotate(0deg);
    }
    to {
      transform: rotate(360deg);
    }
  }

#pl0{
  transform: rotate(180deg);

}

#pl1{
  transform: rotate(225deg);
}

#pl2{
  transform: rotate(270deg);
}

#pl3{
  transform: rotate(315deg);
}

#pl4{
  transform: rotate(360deg);
}

#pl5{
  transform: rotate(405deg);
}

#pl6{
  transform: rotate(450deg);
}

#pl7{
  transform: rotate(495deg);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons'/>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style/style.css" />
</head>
<body>
    <header class="t-site-header">
        <div class="full_container" id="mobile_control">
            <div class="bottom">
                <div class="nav">
                    <span id="next" onclick="moon('next')" class="action"><i class="material-icons">keyboard_arrow_left</i></span>
                    <span id="prev" onclick="moon('prev')" class="action"><i class="material-icons">keyboard_arrow_right</i></span>
                </div>
                <div class="orbit">
                    <div class="planet_container">
                        <div class="planet pt earth" id="pl0">
                            <div class="moon">
                                <span></span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="planet mars" id="pl1">
                            <div class="moon">
                                <span></span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="planet jupiter" id="pl2">
                            <div class="moon">
                                <span></span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="planet saturn" id="pl3">
                            <div class="moon">
                                <span></span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="planet uranus" id="pl4">
                            <div class="moon">
                                <span></span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="planet neptune" id="pl5">
                            <div class="moon">
                                <span></span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="planet mercury" id="pl6">
                            <div class="moon">
                                <span></span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="planet venus" id="pl7">
                            <div class="moon">
                                <span></span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="name_container">
                        <p class="pn" id="show_pathname"></p>
                        <p class="more">READ MORE</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </header>
    <script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js'></script>
    <script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/hammer.js/2.0.8/hammer.min.js'></script>
    <script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animejs/2.0.2/anime.min.js'></script><script  src="./js/script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: {
  "message": "Uncaught ReferenceError: Hammer is not defined",

Comment: <script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js'></script>
 <script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/hammer.js/2.0.8/hammer.min.js'></script>
 <script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animejs/2.0.2/anime.min.js'></script>

Comment: edit your questions rather than post comments - I updated the snippet as an example of how to do this

Comment: Now make it show what you rmean - I see no "circular" thing

Comment: Please see [mcve]

Comment: Ok. It's now good? Please any help my issue.